# Can i define a trait implementing another trait’s associated function when there is already a generic implementation for the trait Im implementing?

Tags: rust

Context: I am working with an external crate that defines a trait `ExternalTrait`
eg

```rust
pub trait ExternalTrait {
    fn associated_func() -> i32;
}
```

I have several types that have almost identical implementations of said trait, differing only by a single value, so I want to defined my own trait implementing the external one where the only required definition is the value that differs.

e.g.

```rust
trait MyImplementation {
    fn custom_value() -> i32;
}
```

One way i attempted to do this that does not work is

```rust
impl ExternalTrait for dyn MyImplementation {
    fn associated_func() -> i32 {
        &Self::custom_value()
    }
}
```

which fails because MyImplementation, having an associated function, is not object safe.

What does work is

```rust
impl<T> ExternalTrait for T
where
    T: MyImplementation,
{
    fn associated_func() -> i32 {
        T::custom_value()
    }
}
```

which is great, except that the external crate I'm working with already has a generic implementation for that trait, like this:

```rust
impl<'a, Y> ExternalTrait for &'a Y
where
    Y: ?Sized,
    Y: ExternalTrait,
{
    fn associated_func() -> i32 {
        10
    }
}
```

which understandably conflicts with the one I'm defining. So the question is, is there a way to support my use-case, aside from using macros?

Cheers

e: additional context. The above was just me trying to come up with a minimal example. The actual external trait that I'm running into this in practice is https://docs.rs/juniper/0.15.1/juniper/trait.GraphQLType.html and conflicting implementation is https://docs.rs/juniper/0.15.1/juniper/trait.GraphQLType.html#impl-GraphQLType%3CS%3E-for-%26%27e%20T. It is possible to implement it for a concrete struct just fine, e.g.

`impl GraphQLType<DefaultScalarValue> for MyStruct`

Comment: How is it possible to implement `ExternalTrait` for any type whatsoever? The blanket implementation provided by the trait's crate seems to cover all types, sized and unsized. Just defining a `struct X;` and trivially implementing `ExternalTrait for X` fails with a conflicting implementation. ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eca293fb83b7739e330b0b3504b94ccb).)

Comment: My example might be too minimal then, i added some additional info about the real usecase.

Comment: Made a change to the minimal example, so that it is in line with the real code. Please feel free to edit it more, if my change was not fully correct.

Comment: I think the main issue with allowing this is that Rust would have to check every blanket implementation of every trait when you implement a trait to make sure that you're not creating conflicting blanket implementations. Slightly related is [issue #20400](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20400), about impls on traits known to be disjoint due to having differing associated types.

Comment: that makes sense, my intent is to figure out if there was another approach I could take to handle deduplicating code in a situation like this. There is, though, which is macros, its just heavyweight and I was hoping to avoid it